Would it be possible to form dense metal using a sol gel technique?
I was trying reduce some silver salt AgNO3 into elemental metal by thermal reduction I mixed it with citric acid and formed a solution and poured it into a circular cap (makeshift mould) and what I ended up with after putting it in a oven was a porous structure of what I assume is silver with some white residue over it. This made me wonder if there is a way I could form a dense product using this method maybe make a thin ring or something. I think the porosity is due to carbon dioxide evolution. Does anyone have any experience with this or sol gel technique in general that can help me to form a denser product. I know traditionally sol gel is mostly used to form nano particles.


An $\ce{AgNO3 + HOC(CO2H)(CH2CO2H)2}$ mixture evolves a great amount of gas -- of course there would be bubbles.
There is no need for a reducing agent: $\ce{AgNO3}$ decomposes at 400°C, and, "the decomposition of silver nitrate yields elemental silver."
It is well known that molten silver absorbs a large volume of oxygen from the air. As it solidifies, that oxygen bubbles out and not only creates defects, but can cause the partially solidified silver to spatter. There are techniques to deal with that issue.

If your goal is to make a ring, you've chosen an expensive and inefficient path. $\ce{AgNO3}$ is far more expensive, per gram of silver (e.g., ~US\$3/g for $\ce{AgNO3}$, or ~US\$4.50/g of Ag at Flinn Scientific), than buying silver metal (currently, about US\$1/g).
You might profitably learn the lost-wax process to cast metal, instead.

The reason I added citric acid was to form a gel that can hold some shape. I wanted to just try and see if there is a good way to work silver like this into some intricate shapes easily without handling molten metal I guess. Already have AgNO3 so not really concerned about the cost as much as exploring the process.
